# how to get order list from my store at shopify

Tags: node.js, rest, oauth-2.0, shopify, access-token

```
const axios = require('axios');
require('dotenv').config();


// Shopify Store의 정보
const API_KEY = process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY;
const API_PASSWORD = process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET;
const STORE_URL = process.env.SHOPIFY_STORE_URL;

// Shopify API를 통해 제품 목록 가져오기
async function getProductList() {
  try {
    const url = `${STORE_URL}/admin/api/2023-04/products.json`;
    const response = await axios.get(url, {
      auth: {
        username: API_KEY,
        password: API_PASSWORD
      }
    });
    const products = response.data.products;
    for (const product of products) {
   
      console.log(product.title);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
}

// 제품 목록 가져오기
getProductList();
```

now i can get result from shopify about stores product data but i need to take access token so
what i need to add more to get Access token and scopes from shopify in this code?

now i can get result from shopify about stores product data but i need to take access token so
what i need to add more to get Access token and scopes from shopify in this code?

Comment: You have to include your token in the custom header `X-Shopify-Access-Token`. See [REST Admin API Reference](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest#authentication).

Comment: i mean i don't know how to get access token i already got secret key and api key